# How to access array data via pointer instead of copy in OpenSceneGraph?

Tags: c++, openscenegraph

I write a small animation program with OpenSceneGraph(osg). In each frame, I should update the models(vertex position,normal, color and other stuff) in the scene.

Now I shoudl convert the data to osg in each frame. The code is like:

```
cog_.vertex_->clear();
cog_.vertex_->push_back(osg::Vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0));
```

However these convertion is very time consuming. So I'm wondering how to access data directly via pointer. I tried but failed. The following is what I did, hope someone can help me to find the problem, or tell me better solution:

First, I wrap the a pointer to osg::Vec3,

```
class vec3_map : public osg::Vec3
{
public:
    typedef osg::Vec3::value_type value_type;
    osg::Vec3::value_type* p_;

    vec3_map() :p_(0) {}
    vec3_map(osg::Vec3::value_type*p, int offset = 0) :p_(p+offset){}

    inline value_type& x() { return *(p_+0); }
    inline value_type& y() { return *(p_+1); }
    inline value_type& z() { return *(p_+2); }

    // some other stuff
};
```

When I want to build an array of vec3_map, I found that osg use a tempalte to typedef Vec3Array, but there isn't any type for a pointer, so I choose the closet one (I know pointer is a variable with unsigned long int type):

```
 typedef osg::TemplateArray<vec3_map, osg::Array::UIntArrayType, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT> Vec3_map_Array;
```

With this definition, I can rewrite my problem to the following:

```
#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <fstream>

#include <vector>
#include <osg/Group>
#include <osg/Geometry>
#include <osgViewer/Viewer>
#include <osg/Vec3>

class vec3_map : public osg::Vec3
{
public:
typedef osg::Vec3::value_type value_type;
osg::Vec3::value_type* p_;

vec3_map() :p_(0) {}
vec3_map(osg::Vec3::value_type*p, int offset = 0) :p_(p + offset) {}

inline value_type* ptr() { return p_; }
inline const value_type* ptr() const { return p_; }

inline value_type& operator [] (int i) { return *(p_ + i); }
inline value_type operator [] (int i) const { return *(p_ + i); }

inline value_type& x() { return *(p_ + 0); }
inline value_type& y() { return *(p_ + 1); }
inline value_type& z() { return *(p_ + 2); }

inline value_type x() const { return *(p_); }
inline value_type y() const { return *(p_ + 1); }
inline value_type z() const { return *(p_ + 2); }
};


typedef osg::TemplateArray<vec3_map, osg::Array::UIntArrayType, 1,     GL_UNSIGNED_INT> Vec3_map_Array;

struct point_data
{
 point_data(float xx, float yy, float zz) { x = xx; y = yy; z = zz; }
 float x;
 float y;
 float z;
};

osg::Geode* create_point_node(boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<point_data> > ptr)
{
 osg::Geode *geode_ = new osg::Geode;
 osg::Geometry* geometry_ = new osg::Geometry;
 Vec3_map_Array* vertex_ = new Vec3_map_Array;
 osg::DrawElementsUInt* point_idx_ = new osg::DrawElementsUInt;

 vertex_->reserve(ptr->size());
 point_idx_->reserve(ptr->size());

 vec3_map vm;
 std::vector<point_data> & pd = *ptr;
 for (size_t i = 0; i < ptr->size(); ++i)
 {
    vertex_->push_back(vec3_map(&(pd[i].x)));
    point_idx_->push_back(i);
 }

 geometry_->setVertexArray(vertex_);
 geometry_->addPrimitiveSet(point_idx_);
 geode_->addDrawable(geometry_);
 return geode_;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<point_data> > pd(new std::vector<point_data>);
 pd->push_back(point_data(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
 pd->push_back(point_data(2.0, 2.0, 2.0));

 osgViewer::Viewer viewer;
 osg::Node *node = create_point_node(pd);
 viewer.setSceneData(node);
 return viewer.run();
}
```

However, this problem crashes. I'm not sure whether I can do something like this.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for you reply @m.s. I have upload a minimal test with data to the following link https://github.com/tfjiang/test_osg_vec_map.git

Comment: this is by far not **minimal**. reduce as much code as possible, then [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33417906/edit) and insert the code there instead of linking to off-site resources.

Comment: @m.s. Thank you. But I think this example is quite minimal. To demonstrate my situation, I  construct a scene with only one render node, which is loaded from a local file. I think reducing it will make it not executable.

Comment: well, I do not consider hundred lines of code (and more) to be minimal.

Comment: @m.s. Ok. Let me reduce it again.

Comment: @m.s. I reduced the code into a minimal case. Could you please help to have a look?

Comment: what is the reason to use `vec3_map`? why don't you directly fill your points in a `osg::Vec3Array` instead of first creating a `std::vector<point_data>` and then having to convert to a osg format?

Comment: @m.s. That's because in my real application, the data output by other algorithm is a vector of point_data, so I want to convert it to osg format with minimal cost, like only using pointer instead of copying data.

Comment: Yes, I did the test. I should update >500K points each frame, the average cost time is 0.08s which slow down my FPS.

Comment: I suggest having a look at the [osgsharedarray example](http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg/browser/OpenSceneGraph/trunk/examples/osgsharedarray/osgsharedarray.cpp) which shows *"how to create your own subclass of osg::Array. This
is useful if your application has data in its own form of storage and you don't
want to make another copy into one of the predefined osg::Array classes."*

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll try this solution. It looks quite promising.